# Example of TreeTableModel and TreeTableNode

Tags: java, swingx, treetable, jxtreetable

Despite my googling I have yet to find an example implementation of a `TreeTableModel` and a `TreeTableNode`. I'm trying to implement a `JXTreeTable` and am not really sure what to do.